# Multiline TextBox not showing line

Tags: asp.net

So, I have a TextBox with TextMode = "MultiLine" property. When I try to fill the Text property with some text that comes from a database, for some reason the last line is not showing. I happens to be a embed code from a youtube video, I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code and the expected text from the db?

Comment: Can you show us the output of the page specifically around the textbox, Right Click, View Source from the web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Does the code from the database have a double quote in it? If so, then you need to escape the quotes, replace double quotes with single quotes, or use HTMLEncode function.